# Downloading google-services.json through api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firebase, google-play-services

Is there any way to download the google-services.json from our firebase project console through some api and not manually.

Comment: There's currently no public API for this.

Comment: is it possible to download that using curl ?

Comment: Not unless you can get an authentication token for your Google account, which is not really a thing that's intended for you to do.

Comment: is there any other better way to download google-services.json file?

Comment: what are the steps to get authentication token for google account..?